# How to concatenate strings escaped by braces in Tcl?

Tags: tcl, expect

I write regex in Expect script and want use **([0-9]+)\r** as regex pattern. To prevent of **[...]** substitution I use curved braces:

```
expect -re {([0-9]+)\r} {...}
```

But **\r**  in **{...}** have no special meaning in braces (treated as two chars). I try

```
expect -re {([0-9]+)}\r {...}
```

But this take parsing error. I try

```
expect -re [concat {([0-9]+)} "\r"] {...}
```

But **concat** add space between args.

**PS**. I know another solution with **"..."** quotes by quoting **[**:

```
expect -re "(\[0-9]+)\r" {...}
```

but would like hear solution with **{...}** quoting style...

Comment: Tcl's RE engine — which Expect uses under the hood — most certainly does interpret `\r` as a carriage return. However, it's rather uncommon to want to match against it (but it _is_ commonly used in the string you send to the spawned program). I wonder what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct: \r has no meaning inside { }, for that you need to use double quote, but need to escape the square brackets:

```
expect -re "(\[0-9\]+)\r" ...
```

If you want to concatenate:

```
set expression {([0-9]+)}
append expression "\r"
expect -r $expression
```

Comment: Instead of **"(\[0-9\]+)\r"** I use **"(\[0-9]+)\r"** (omit second backslash). This work but I don't know if is this correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than doing one of these:
`regexp [string map {([0-9]+):spaceholder:} ":spaceholder:" "\r"] ...`
`regexp [list (\[0-9\]+)\r] ...`
My examples are with regexp, because i never saw "" (string) working in the `regexp` command as pattern, only with a list.
You could try something like this tho: `set p {([0-9]+)}; append p \r` and then using `$p` or just `set p {([0-9]+)}; regexp $p\r ...`

Your problem with the space: `[join "a b" ""]`

Comment: What do you mean "no other way"? There are certainly other ways to accomplish the end goal of concatenating strings.